# If I had 4 different internet USB dongles for 1 laptop, would each dongle use a different IP address?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, usb, ip

This question is completely theoretical to help my understanding of how IP addresses work. I had a look around online and cannot find any answers for my question.

> If I had 4 different internet USB dongles for 1 laptop, would each
>   dongle use a different IP address?

**Let me set an example...** If a website stores your IP address when you create an account, if I was to create a new account on that website, creating each one with a different dongle, would that site store a different IP address for each account? or could it somehow know that all those accounts were created from 1 machine?

Any help or advice is appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes they would.
Which one your computer would use for internet I don't know, but in production setups it's not uncommon to have several IP addresses for servers.

Comment: Ahh cool, So if a website was to track my IP address, Would it track a different IP for each dongle I use on that site? @MikaelKjær

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand correctly, but you would only connect with 1 IP address at a time. I am unsure how to cycle through the different IP addresses without disconnecting each dongle.

Comment: Okay, Please see the example I have added to the question @MikaelKjær

Comment: The website would probably store a cookie in your browser. If you were to use incognito mode it would probably be unable to link those accounts.

Answer (score 0):

You can have as many network interfaces as the hardware will support, all with different (local) IP addresses, no matter if it's USB devices, built-in devices, ethernet cards, or whatever.

However, your publicly visible IP address (what a websites stores in the logs) *only* depends on your ISP, and the way you are connected to your ISP. And this publicly visible IP address is *not* connected in any way to your local IP addresses.

So whatever networking hardware you use won't change what or how many public IP addresses you have.

If you want to masquerade as using different public IP addresses, for whatever reason, or if you want to share your public IP address with many other people. use e.g. VPNs (virtual private networks) or web-proxies.

Comment: Ahh cool, with this in mind, would the example I spoke about in my question work?

Comment: You mean, "if I used 4 different VPNs, and created 4 accounts on some website using a different VPN each time, would it store 4 different IPs, one for each account?" Yes, it would. Not that creating several accounts with different IPs is going to help you if you plan something nasty -- sooner or later you'll run out of VPNs to use after you get banned. So don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

In general each dongle uses whatever ip-address the ISP assigns to it. In most cases this is a random ip-address out of the pool of ip-addresses that belongs to the provider.
It is even possible that the provider gives a non-public ip-address that gets mapped to a normal (public) internet ip-address further down the line. (This is called carrier-grade NAT.) In that case multiple clients of the ISP can share the same public ip-address.

It would be exceedingly rare (but not impossible) to get the same ip-address twice in a row, even on the same dongle.

Any web-site that identifies it's clients by ip-address alone is run by people who don't know what they are doing. An IP-address by itself is pretty meaningless. (It is also pretty easy to falsify or hide your own ip-address.)

There are numerous other (and better) ways to track a individual PC. (E.g. cookies to name just 1). IP-address one of the less useful ones.

Comment: Ahh cool, with this in mind, would the example I spoke about in my question work?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you understand under an "Internet USB Dongle" if you mean a Wifi stick you most likely are behind a [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) so so the Public IP address would be the Same since they are connecting to the same Router.The local IP address in YOUR Wifi network would differ because of the different Hardware addresses MAC of the dongles. It is however possible to Spoof the MAC addresses so all dongles would appear to be the same device to the Router.
If your "Internet USB Dongles" are UMTS or LTE sticks with a Sim card etc it would be different then every reconnect would probably get you a new IP. Your ISP however would still see if its the same device because of your IMSI and IMEI. A Webpage would not know if you switched the Dongle or simply reconnected it since this information is only known to your ISP.
User tracking like this would most likely be done with a [Cookie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie) which is a file stored by the webpage on your computer to inform the webpage about who you are, so a session on the page would not be interrupted by changing IPs.